# How to convert a number type value to empty string?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I'm using this `TypeScript` data structure (TypeScript is important because of types):

```
  private data = {
    parent_id: 0,
    name: ''
  };
```

I want to get this:

```
  private data = {
    parent_id: '',
    name: ''
  };
```

How can I convert the `parent_id:number` field to `parent_id:string`?

Comment: You need to cast it, as it is called. Scroll down to `type assertions` on this site, to get some info
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to do?  There is not enough information here for a meaningful answer.

Comment: You could eventually have an union type `number|string`, but to be honest, it's probably much cleaner to declare an entirely new type. In any case you have to run the conversion manually.

Comment: @jcalz : the `parnet_id` is created originally as a number, but the backend accept only higher than zero integer or empty string. `0` isn't acceptable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an interface like:

```
interface DataInterface {
  parent_id: number | string;
  name: string;
}
```

Then you can define the object:

```
const data: DataInterface = {
  parent_id: 0,
  name: 'foo'
};
```

and this would be allowed too:

```
data.parent_id = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

We can actually tell the compiler to make this distinction for us with a conditional type and the `typeof` keyword. See below:

```
type isZero<N> = N extends (0 | '') ? '' : number;
type ParentIdType = isZero<typeof instance.id>;

interface Data {
    parent_id: ParentIdType;
    name: string;
}

class SomeClassWithData {
    readonly id = <your value>;

    private data: Data = {
        parent_id: this.id,
        name: 'foo',
    }
}

const instance = new SomeClassWithData();
```

---

### How It Works

This works because the compiler infers constants and readonly class properties as their literal types. Here's an example of how it works when `instance.id = 0;`:

```
type isZero<N> = N extends (0 | '') ? '' : number; // '' because 0 extends 0
type ParentIdType = isZero<typeof instance.id>;  // isZero<0>

interface Data {
    parent_id: ParentIdType;  // ParentIdType --> isZero<0> --> ''
    name: string;
}

class SomeClassWithData {
    readonly id = 0; // inferred as type 0 instead of number because it's a readonly property

    private data: Data = {
        parent_id: this.id,  // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type '""'.
        name: 'foo',
    }
}

const instance = new SomeClassWithData();
```

This solution is nice because

`instance.id = 1;`

and

`instance.id = '';`

are allowed but

`instance.id = 0;`

and

`instance.id = 'foo';`

will throw an error.

Comment: nice solution, but I need to accept `0` and `''` too. This is the point of the question. I need to accept these values: `''`, `0`, `1`, and other integers higher than `0`. But only empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do would to simply define their ID as a string prior to inputting it in your data class, i.e.

```
 id = '0';
 private data = {
     parent_id: id,
     name: ''
 };
```

This way throughout, if you have any other IDs as strings, you can make them a variable and use the `.toString()` function which will automatically convert the number to a string and then you could copy what I did above.